# How to make a discord.py event listener that deletes any new thread in a specific channel forum?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to make an event that listens for a new thread created in a forum and deletes it if it doesn't match the name requisite

I've tried this, that works for every forum channels, but I can't find a way to make it working just for one specific forum. The problem is on the line `if thread.channel.id == forum_channel_id:` that gives me an attribute error, saying that Thread object has no channel attribute

```
@bot.event
async def on_thread_create(thread):
    forum_channel_id = 1069778474815979570
    if thread.channel.id == forum_channel_id:
        return
    if thread.name.startswith("Request #"):
        async for entry in thread.guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.thread_create):
            user = entry.user
            break
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Request Succesfully Done", description="The thread named ''{}'' was succesfully created.".format(thread.name), color=discord.Color.green())
        await user.send(embed = embed)
    else:
        async for entry in thread.guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.thread_create):
            user = entry.user
            break
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Invalid Request", description="The thread named ''{}'' could not be created.".format(thread.name), color=discord.Color.red())
        await user.send(embed = embed)
        await thread.delete()
```

Any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean, [I don't see it in the documents either as an attribute...](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Thread)

...but it *looks* like what you really want is the origin ID of where the thread was created, which is what [`Thread.parent_id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Thread.parent_id) will give you.

> `parent_id`
>
> The parent `TextChannel` or `ForumChannel` ID this thread belongs to.